# how to get property value from java bean in javascript without replacing the special characters

Tags: javascript, struts2, character

I have a struts2 application and I am trying to show a KML layer on top of Google Earth using the Google Earth plug-in. I am using:    ge.parseKml(kmlString)

If I put the KML string in the script section such as
`var kmlString ='<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\">  <Document> <Camera> <longitude>-122.444633</longitude> <latitude>37.801899</latitude> <altitude>139.629438</altitude> <heading>-70.0</heading> <tilt>75</tilt> </Camera>  <Placemark> <name>Placemark from KML string</name> <Point>   <coordinates>-122.448425,37.802907,0</coordinates> </Point> </Placemark>  </Document> </kml>';`

then the marker shows up on the globe. The problem is that this KML string is not fixed, but will be generated after the user selects certain values. So I am getting the KML string from the java bean class property "kmlStr" like this:

`var kmlString='<s:property value="kmlStr"/>';`

The problem is that the following special characters are replaced  `'<' becomes '&lt;' and '>' becomes '&gt;'`
This breaks the "parseKml" method since the greater than and less then symbols are not interpreted (the marker does not show up).

So the question is how do I can get the string from the java bean property 'kmlStr' without
`'<' and '>' being replaced to "&lt;" and "&gt;"` respectively ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use either:

```
var kmlString='<s:property value="kmlStr" escape="false"/>';
```

or

```
var kmlString='<s:property value="kmlStr" escapeHtml="false"/>';
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. The first solution works.  I wish I would checked the s:property documentation.